# Hive Data selecting latest value based on timestamp

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table having the following columns.

```
C1,C2,Process TimeStamp,InsertDateTimeStamp
p1,v1,2014-01-30 12:15:23,2013-10-01 05:34:23 
p1,v2,2014-01-31 05:11:34,2013-12-01 06:12:31 
p1,v3,2014-01-31 07:16:05,2012-09-01 07:45:20 
p2,v4,2014-02-01 09:22:52,2013-12-01 06:12:31 
p2,v5,2014-02-01 09:22:52,2012-09-01 07:45:20
```

Now, I want to fetch unique row for each primary key based on latest `Process TimeStamp`.

If `Process TimeStamp` is same then row having latest `InsertDateTimeStamp` should be chosen.

So, my result should be.

```
p1,v3,2014-01-31 07:16:05,2012-09-01 07:45:20 
p2,v4,2014-02-01 09:22:52,2013-12-01 06:12:31
```

How to achieve this via HiveQL ?

I am currently using hive 0.10. I can not use subquery with IN or EXISTS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select C1, s.C2, s.ProcessTimeStamp, s.InsertDateTimeStamp from (
  select C1, max(named_struct('unixtime', unix_timestamp(ProcessTimeStamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'C2', C2, 'ProcessTimeStamp', ProcessTimeStamp, 'InsertDateTimeStamp', InsertDateTimeStamp)) as s
  from my_table group by C1
) t;
```

Doing the max of a struct compares by the first field, then the second field, etc. So if you struct everything together, with the parsed timestamp value first, you get a struct representing that row. Then just un-struct it by selecting out the individual fields.

Answer (score 5):

You should strongly consider upgrading Hive, this can be easily done with a window function included in Hive 11+ using row_number(partition by c1 order by ProcessTimeStamp desc) in a sub-select an selecting the first row in an outer select.

You don't need to update your entire cluster to upgrade Hive, you can just deploy it to one node.