# How to use oozie to find data path in HDFS with uncertain date

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a Hive table partitioned by date(e.g. 20150730)

Furthermore, I created a hive query which consumes today's partition date and the most recent previous partition date which is not necessary to be yesterday. (e.g. 20150730 and 20150728)

I want to use oozie to execute this hive query daily, but how can I find the previous partition date? (again the previous proportional date is unpredictable)

Comment: can you create hive query that can answer what is the previous partition date ?

Answer (score 0):

The Same kind of ques have been answed in the link.
[Hive Data selecting latest value based on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590572/hive-data-selecting-latest-value-based-on-timestamp)

please have a check, you might need to apply some modification in mention example.

As you mention Date is unpredictable, but believe it should be in format

also You can try someting like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(date) FROM partition_table ORDER BY usage_dt DESC limit 2;
```

these will give u previous Date even though if its not predictate...