# How to get latest inserted data in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have table as,

```
create table names
(name string,insert_time timestamp)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile;

select * from names;
OK
abc 2017-05-06 10:11:30
abc 2017-05-07 11:15:40
pqr 2017-05-06 12:11:10
```

I want to fetch only latest inserted data.
O/P should be as follows,

```
abc    2017-05-07 11:15:40
pqr    2017-05-06 12:11:10
```

Please Guide how to get this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive Data selecting latest value based on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590572/hive-data-selecting-latest-value-based-on-timestamp)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [`order by` and `limit`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy):

```
SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 2
```

*order by desc* will sort the records by timestamp in decreasing order, *limit n* will return only the first *n* records.